# Affine transformation read order

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, affine-geometry

I would like to ask a question about affine matrix transformations, specifically a mathematical explanation about why these two ways to interpret them are equivalent.

Suppose I have a translation matrix T (for simplicity 2D) and a rotation matrix R as follows:

$$
 T= \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & tx \\
        0 & 1 & ty \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
 R= \begin{bmatrix}
        \cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0 \\
        \sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Suppose:
$$
tx = 0 , ty = 2, \theta = 45^{ \circ }
$$

Now if I transform a quad applying translation and rotation to every vertex in this order: R * T * Vertex (Column vector), I obtain this:

[image: After Translation]

[image: After Rotation]

Since both translation and rotation transforms are done around the origin, considering T first and R after. However this is equivalent to considering R first and T after modifying the quad relative to itself and not the origin:

[image: After Rotation]

[image: After Translation]

The result is the same. Why is this equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the agreement. Usually it is preferred to read $(f*g)(x)$ as $f(g(x))$ when we talk about functions, operators and etc., but You can put it as You like, generally, with remark about your own agreement.